# Get current user screenname from Twitter

Tags: twitter

Is there a way to get the screenname of the current logged in user?

The [`show`](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/show) requires `id` or `user_id` or `screen_name`, but I don't have any of those.

---

I could only think about a workaround, that would be to make a request to twitter.com and get the contents of the `<span id="me_name">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible without oAuth.

The only workaround is the one mentioned on the question.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried account/verify_credentials

Comment: It asks for authorization. I don't have the access token at this point.

Comment: right, you need that for the function, have you tried @Anywhere, pretty easy to setup

Comment: with anywhere you can do something like :

twttr.anywhere(function(T) {
  if(T.isConnected()) {
     var currentUser = T.currentUser;
     screenName = currentUser.data('screen_name');
  }
});

Comment: Trying to use that script T.isConnected() returned false, and I was online at Twitter. I just need to know how to get the T.currentUser.data("screen_name"), I don't need anything else.

Comment: weird.. it should be working both on REST and @Anywhere, what you can do is clear all you browser cache, then use anywhere to connect, once connected, you should get the screen name, you can put it inside auth_complete and use it like this :
T.bind("authComplete", function (e, user) {     
   currentUser = T.currentUser;
   screenName = currentUser.data('screen_name');    
});

Comment: How one can consider this as an answer? Don't you think you should post this in comment instead answer?